# Why are web browsers browsers, but I am a surfer?

Tags: word-usage, names, internet

What is the origin of the name of a program being used to access the Internet is a *browser*, but a human looking around on the internet is *surfing*?

Why is there this discrepancy?

Comment: I belive the phrase Internet surfing comes from channel surfing on the tv.

Comment: Because language isn't predictable.

Comment: Because surfing is more cool than browsing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the term "web surfing" was deliberately coined in the very early days of the web by Jean Armour Polly. She describes the event in [this link.](http://www.netmom.com/about-net-mom/25-meet-net-mom/26-surfing-the-internet.html) Here is some of what she says:

> As I wrote the article, I knew it would be one of the first articles of its type...
>
> In casting about for a title for the article , I weighed many possible metaphors. I wanted something that expressed the fun I had using the Internet, as well as hit on the skill, and yes, endurance necessary to use it well. I also needed something that would evoke a sense of randomness, chaos, and even danger.

Her original article, I guess, went viral, before going viral was the thing to do.

Here is a [link to the original article.](http://internet.eserver.org/Surfing-Internet.txt)

The term "browser" was coined by Tim Berners-Lee, the original designer of the web protocols, and used in the very first grant proposal for the design he was proposing. See [Wikipedia on the history of the web.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Wide_Web#History)

Answer (score 2):

It's clearly to distinguish between the user and that which is being used.
Can you imagine if we were called *'web browsers'*.

*'Web browsers browse the internet using web browsers'*

This might be technically correct but it's quickly confusing to say the least.

Comment: Joe, I think you have misunderstood Tim's question. I think he is asking why, when _browser_ and _surfer_ are apparently formed in the same way, one means the tool, and the other means the user of the tool. As you say _browser_ can be used to mean the person, but _surfer_ cannot be used to mean the tool.#

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer is mostly chance. Some *-er* words are tools, some are actors, and some can be either. Consider *cooker*, *steamer* *(deep fat) fryer*, which are all tools, against *baker*, who is a person.

When *-er* denotes a tool, it is usually a tool which actually performs the relevant act, rather than something incidental: a *browser* doesn't work by its own volition (usually!) but it does go sampling things around the web. I always found the word *planter* strange (for a container in which things are planted) for this reason. (Though thinking of it, it's possible that this is a different *-er*, a transfer of the French ending *-ière*, as in *jardinière*, "planter").